# Java - having char input in string.replace() problems

Tags: java, string, char

Is there a way to fix this issue with creating a new string variable equal to that character

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mean_and_scary {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Text:");
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        char leftchar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        char rightchar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        char removechar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        int width = scanner.nextInt();
        text = text.replace(removechar, ""); // at this point
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(text);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? can you explain with an example value?

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: Replace `""` (`String`) by `''` (`Char`) because now you try to find a method don't exist.

Comment: `'\u0000'` I would said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that there is no method in the String class with the arguments (char, String)

Try this: `text = text.replace(removechar + "", "");`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the line with below :

```
text = text.replace(String.valueOf(removechar), ""); // at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happen because the method `.replace(char,String)` of `String` class don't exist so they can find it.

[Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    "Test".replace("",""); // OK because the method replace with params CharSequence,CharSequence exist
    "Test".replace('e', '\u0000'); // OK because the method replace with params char,char exist
    "Test".replace('\u0000', ""); // Not OK because the method don't exist 
}
```